# How to hermetically seal a circuit in a visual & bluetooth transparent solid cube ~2-3"?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials, chemical-engineering

I want to encase a circuit in a ~2-3" cube of some kind of visually and Bluetooth transparent material.  What material will do this?

Something like:
1. half fill a cube shaped mold with liquid or jelly material
2. add circuit
3. fill up mold so that circuit is 'floating' in the middle and sealed.
4. wait for material to dry
5. circuit is now sealed within sold, transparent cube, and can be controlled via Bluetooth from iPhone app.

I want to demonstrate that the circuit with battery and Bluetooth communication can be controlled wirelessly from iPhone management app.

Answer (score 4):

The process of encasing electronics in a material is called *potting*.

Various resin materials can be used, such as polyester resin or epoxy.  Discussion of the types of resin can be found in this article on [Potting Compound Types](http://www.pottingsolutions.com/my%20site/Technology/resin%20type.htm).  Several sources have recommended epoxy as the easiest material to begin with, but it is *much* more expensive than polyester resin, so epoxy may not be practical if you want a deep casting.  Examples of some specific products include this [clear polyester casting resin](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0018N9E3M) and [3M epoxy potting compound](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000X5G6O6).  Note the small 1.5 fl oz size of the epoxy compound versus the 32 fl oz of the polyester compound.  Some casting resins may not be designed specifically for electronics, and are often marketed for various kinds of arts and crafts, but might work fine for your purposes.

Potting electronics can be a complex process, since it can trap the heat produced by electronics and can cause physical stress due to thermal expansion/contraction.  A useful introduction to some of these issues can be found in the article [Potting Hints](http://www.pottingsolutions.com/my%20site/Technology/potting_hints.htm).

Comment: To address the specific question, do you know of any potting compounds that are optically clear? I would imagine that most potting compounds don't cause much RF interference and so they should let the bluetooth through, right?

Comment: Most electrically insulating, pure potting compounds should be RF-transparent, but to improve thermal conductivity or mechanical/physical characteristics, other materials may be introduced that do impede radio frequencies.